# How do I import a name from pandas.io.common?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Having some trouble with the below code:

```
import requests_cache
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.common import ZipFile 
from pandas.compat import BytesIO, StringIO, PY2
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-38562bc3a3ef> in <module>
      5 
      6 import pandas as pd
----> 7 from pandas.io.common import ZipFile
      8 from pandas.compat import BytesIO, StringIO, PY2
      9 

ImportError: cannot import name 'ZipFile' from 'pandas.io.common' (//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py)
```

It was working but now it isn't. I have anaconda installed, pandas installed, etc. I am not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you upgraded Pandas.

`ZipFile` originates from the standard library `zipfile`, and Pandas was previously exposing it conditionally with a wrapper prior to v 0.20. In recent versions, you can either use their renamed wrapped version `pandas.io.common.BytesZipFile` or use the vanilla `zipfile.ZipFile`.

I'm just going off the code history. Neither the public API nor release notes mention this, so you should probably regard it as internal code that has no consistency guarantees across versions.